I can't get players to move items
Moving items by the player does not work and produces the error.
Perhaps this is some kind of bug; my other projects had the same error. Hope someone can help me.
I use unity netcode for gameobjects.
Error:
KeyNotFoundException: The given key '0' was not present in the dictionary.
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].get_Item (TKey key) (at <27124aa0e30a41659b903b822b959bc7>:0)
Dragger.SetJointConnectedClientRpc () (at Assets/Scripts/Items/Drag/Dragger.cs:58)

Here's the code of Dragger.cs:
    public Transform dragPosition;
    public Transform _camera;
    public float dragRange;

    public NetworkVariable<NetworkObjectReference> currentDragObject = new NetworkVariable<NetworkObjectReference>(default, NetworkVariableReadPermission.Everyone, NetworkVariableWritePermission.Owner);
    private CustomInput _input;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) return;
        _input = GetComponent<CustomInput>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!IsSpawned || !IsOwner) return;
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(_input.dragItemKey))
        {
            if(currentDragObject.Value.NetworkObjectId != 0)
            {
                SetJointServerRpc();
                currentDragObject.Value = new NetworkObjectReference();
                return;
            }
            if(Physics.Raycast(_camera.position, _camera.forward, out RaycastHit hit, dragRange))
            {
                if(hit.collider.TryGetComponent(out NetworkObject networkObject))
                {
                    if(hit.collider.TryGetComponent(out Rigidbody rigidbody))
                    {
                        if(hit.collider.TryGetComponent(out ConfigurableJoint joint))
                        {
                            currentDragObject.Value = networkObject;
                            SetJointConnectedServerRpc();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    private void SetJointConnectedServerRpc()
    {
        SetJointConnectedClientRpc();
    }

    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    private void SetJointServerRpc()
    {
        ConfigurableJoint joint = NetworkManager.Singleton.SpawnManager.SpawnedObjects[currentDragObject.Value.NetworkObjectId].GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>();
        joint.connectedBody = null;
        joint.xMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Free;
        joint.yMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Free;
        joint.zMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Free;
        joint.angularXMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Free;
        joint.angularYMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Free;
        joint.angularZMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Free;
        //SetJointClientRpc();
    }

I don’t know how much more I need to write so that I can post my question

You have an error in SetJointConnectedClientRpc() but haven't included the code for SetJointConnectedClientRpc() in your question.
